# removing substrings from subdirectory names using values held in list

Tags: python, string, list, subdirectory, os.walk

I have a parent directory that contains a lot of subdirectories. I want to create a script that loops through all of the subdirectories and removes any key words that I have specified in the list variable.

I am not entirely sure how to acheive this.

Currently I have this:

```
import os
directory = next(os.walk('.'))[1]


stringstoremove = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']


for folders in directory:
    os.rename
```

And maybe this type of logic to check to see if the string exists within the subdirectory name:

```
if any(words in inputstring for words in stringstoremove):
    print ("TRUE")
else:
    print ("FALSE")
```

Trying my best to to deconstruct the task, but I'm going round in circles now

Thanks guys

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve? Are you look for code optimization?

Comment: do you want remove those sub directories which match your strings list?

Comment: Hello,

Appologies for the confusion. I will clarify:

If for example there is a subdirectory with a name that contains one or more of the values specified within the list variable, I would like to remove each sub string from the subdirectory's name (essentially replacing the substring with nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startng from your existing code:

```
import os
directory = next(os.walk('.'))[1]

stringstoremove = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']

for folder in directory :
    new_folder = folder
    for r in stringstoremove :
        new_folder = new_folder.replace( r, '')

    if folder != new_folder :  # don't rename if it's the same
        os.rename( folder, new_folder )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename those sub directories which match in your `stringstoremove` list then following script will be helpful.

```
import os
import re

path = "./" # parent directory path
sub_dirs = os.listdir(path)
stringstoremove = ['string1','string2','string3','string4','string5']
for directory_name in sub_dirs:
    if os.path.isdir(path + directory):
        for string in stringstoremove:
            if string in directory_name:
                try:
                    new_name = re.sub(string, "", directory_name)
                    os.rename(path + directory, path + new_name) # rename this directory
                except Exception as e:
                    print (e)
```